# OpenWRT: How can I add a new wireless network without NAT leaving the rest of configuration untouched

Tags: networking, openwrt

**Case scenario** for my [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) router:

```
LAN zone: 192.168.22.x/24
WAN zone: 192.168.11.x/24
```

When connecting to **wireless (WLAN)** I get IP in `192.168.22.x/24` range. But I have multiple devices on my `192.168.11.x/24` network that would like to reach me.

I want to connect via **wireless (WLAN)** and receive `192.168.11.x/24` range IP so all the rest of my `192.168.11.x/24` devices can communicate with my just connected device.

How can this be done **without altering the rest** of the LAN/WAN configuration?

I mean: I don't want to disable **NAT for all devices**, and I have computers at both `192.168.11.x/24` and `192.168.22.x/24` networks, both wired and wirelessly, that must keep working.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you must change your DHCP because if you get 22.x and you want to be in 11.x your Wifi DHCP is set wrong. 
easiest would be to configure your main DHCP (Probably your ISP Router) to a specific range say 11.1 to 100 and your openwrt to 101-200 so that you recieve a similar IP on your Wifi without conflicting your Lan DHCP. then you would not need to change anything in your wan.

But to be clear this is just a guess, without further Details about your network this can not be answered more detailed...